# WCF self hosting or IIS hosting - which is better from performance perspective

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

I'm trying to create a web service that serve around 100 client, include file uploading. Fast respond is a requirement. For such kind of scenario I usually create a WCF web service and hosted in IIS with BasicHttpBinding. It works, but is there a "better" way to archive the same thing? Thanks!

I've looked building a WCF with web socket and host it at server as a window service, but it seems a little complicate:\

Comment: What alternatives have you researched?

Comment: Define "better". Deployment complexity? Scaling (for example load balancing)? Security? Development complexity? Raw speed? It's always a trade-off

Comment: Sorry for being unclear of my question, I'm a beginner in programming. I isn't thoughtful on all those criteria, the first thing came to my mind is the speed/response time, as i heard http request overhead consumes some bandwidth.

Comment: I'm lack of web service experience and looking for alternative than WCF and IIS, as a learning experience, thanks :P

Comment: When clearly Microsoft has new frameworks like SignalR and ASP.NET Core as the future, I wonder why you only know of WCF.

Comment: "Better" is entirely subjective. This question is too broad. Just build a service and see if it is sufficient, or use assembly. https://github.com/nemasu/asmttpd